# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Using Shopify API to post product with body_html

Tags: json, shopify, shopify-api

I am using Shopify API to post a product at Shopify. When I add a lengthy Detail in body_html of my http_request (Which is taking data in JSON format). I want to give complete detail with special characters in it Please give me any solution.

My code is this

```
 {"product":{"title":"Premium LCD Digital Multimeter","body_html":"Premium LCD Digital Multimeter

New Digital Multimeter is an electronic measuring instrument that combines all your most commonly used measurement functions into one unit. This Multimeter comes with measurement and testing functions for voltage, current, resistance, continuity (the connection between two points), testing diodes, and temperature

This Digital Multimeter is a must have testing tool for your toolbox, shed, garage, car trunk, etc. Its portability enables you to be able to take it with you wherever you go and provides you with a multitude of features that helps you achieve the best results every time

Features:

* LCD Display
* Auto power off
* Digital Multimeter
* Handheld Multimeter
* Great tool bag accessory
* Great hardware hacking and reverse engineering
* Portable and versatile, easy to carry around and fits neatly in your tool bag
* Multiple testing functions, diode testing, AC/DC testing, temperature, continuity
* Perfect for home DIY en","product_type":"","vendor":"Abdur Rehman","tags":"blue,green,red","options":[],"images":[
  {
    "src": "https://business.tradingzon.com/images/itemimages/15Json Turneryg1 (261).jpg"
  },
  {
    "src": "https://business.tradingzon.com/images/itemimages/15Json Turneryg2 (159).jpg"
  },
  {
    "src": "https://business.tradingzon.com/images/itemimages/15Json Turneryg3 (143).jpg"
  }
],"variants":[
  {
    "title": "Default Title",
    "barcode": "dsfsr4353",
    "inventory_quantity": 1,
    "option1": "Default Title",
    "price": 10.69,
    "weight": 0.4,
    "weight_unit": "kg",
    "sku": "JSN-YG-02-090",
    "grams": 400,
    "tracked": "true",
    "compare_at_price": 15.45, 
    "inventory_policy": "continue"
  }
]}}
```

Comment: this code represents http_request content that is in json format.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Your description field is not in proper JSON format. There are no newlines and you'll have to use "\n" syntax to tell JSON processor that it's a newline. A useful tool - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: this json is actually in Text Format I have checked.If I changed the description in this Http_request to shorten text it will not causes any exception

Comment: What is the content-type header you're sending?

Comment: `request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                request.Method = "POST";
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonstring);
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
                request.Accept = "application/json";`

Comment: if you're using `application/json; charset=UTF-8` your data should be properly formatted t JSON .. take care of the line breaks and it'll work